# Where to find Java jar files in jdk folder

Tags: java

I want to read and understand Java classes written by Sun engineers.
So I downloaded DJCompiler.
But now am unable to see jars of java Apis in jdk installation folder.

I do see src folder and all required classes in it but i need jar files to open in DJCompiler.

Comment: If you download the jdk, it comes with a src.zip file, which contains the actual source (.java) files so you don't need to decompile

Comment: btw where are those jar files..they should be there right?? or else how we are running programs..so i wnat to see jar files of collections classes

Comment: All the default libraries will be in the JRE system lib when you create a new project, if you are using an IDE

Comment: can you cross check in your installation directory of JRE??? are you able to see Java jar file??? i dont find in my dir...btw am not using IDE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `rt.jar`

On my computer here they are in `.../lib/rt.jar`

Answer (score 0):

All the compiled binaries loaded at JVM start up will be in `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib` or `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext`.

On Windows, it looks something like this

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext
```

All the classes from lang and util packages can be found in `rt.jar`